# background-image hover state

Tags: html, css

I've got a parent div

```
#myParentDiv{
   width: 100px;
   height: 200px;
}
```

Then I've got a child div inside it

```
#myChildDiv{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

inside of the child, I've got a button. The button has a `background-image` set

```
#backgroundIndiseChild{
   background-image: url(/img/img.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 50%;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

**My question:** The cursor changes to `cursor:pointer` when hovered over any part of `#myChildDiv`. How do I make the `cursor` change to pointer only when hovered over `#backgroundIndiseChild` ?

Comment: it should be fine. show us a demo.

Comment: A demo would help but I suspect your problem is because of the `background-size: 50%`. The image is taking up only 50% space but that doesn't mean the other area is not part of the `#backgroundIndiseChild` element.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln41xeyq/

Comment: @Harry you're absolutely correct. How do I rectify this?

Comment: @Becky: This is a bit tricky. Can you clarify on the need for the `background-size: 50%` please?

Comment: @Harry: thanks. This is the space --> `#myParentDiv` and inside it I need to have a button which will scale according to the parent ( `#myParentDiv` ). So I added another div inside it ( `#myChildDiv` ) to hold the button.

Comment: @Becky: I have reworded your question just a bit to make it more about the cursor behavior than the `:hover`. Feel free to roll back if you think it doesn't add much value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the clarification provided in comments, I don't think you need the height and width setting on the `#myChildDiv` at all. You could just use something like in the below snippet. I have used the `content` property instead of the `background-image` and set the `height` and `width` to 50%.

```css
#myParentDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f60;
}
#backgroundIndiseChild {
  content: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="myParentDiv">
  <div id="myChildDiv">
    <div id="backgroundIndiseChild"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To vertically center the `content`, you could use the approach mentioned in the below snippet if your image is always going to be 25% height and 50% width of the parent. It positions the image's container absolutely at 50% from the `top` and then uses `transform: translateY(-50%)` to vertically center it. This is the approach I would suggest. (**Note:** I have used viewport units `vh` for the parent to illustrate responsiveness).

```css
#myParentDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 30vh;
  height: 60vh;
  border: 1px solid #f60;
}
#backgroundIndiseChild {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  content: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  height: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="myParentDiv">
  <div id="myChildDiv">
    <div id="backgroundIndiseChild"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. `#backgroundIndiseChild` would not display if there's no size specified to `#myChildDiv`?

Comment: @Becky: Yes, you need to set some explicit height & width or add some content to the `div`. Otherwise there is nothing to be shown and hence the image would remain invisible. This is the reason why I have used the `content` property in the answer instead of `background-image`.

Comment: I just realised you've edited your answer. that seem to work. The reason I had `background-position: 50%;` was to center it inside `#myParentDiv`. How can I vertically center it ?

Comment: @Becky: Both horizontally and vertically centered or only vertical?

Comment: @Becky: That is another tricky piece because you would then have to position it absolutely and then the above snippet won't work :(

Comment: @Becky: I have updated my answer with a possible approach for achieving vertical centering. Check if it fits your case.